# UIWebView webViewDidStartLoad not called

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I post this message because i haven't found any answer.

I send a request to my `UIWebView`, `webViewDidStartLoad` is not called. I need to use the method reload, and then it will work. By the way the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called then twice.

If i'm using a test url (like say Google), i will not get any problem. So that it not seems to be from my code.

But here, I'm calling a ugly site who use lot of angular JS (and i don't know how it has been made). Strange things is that it's working fine on Safari.

What i don't understand is that it just get "stuck" in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`. But after no callback. Nothing happen, even (`didFailLoadWithError:`).
Any idea?

***** EDIT *************

Ok i found the problem, but that's still a strange related issue. I've found the solution trying to send you the code, and i couldn't believe that the code was actually working.

the fact is that i was calling http request while my web view was hidden, and i don't know why, the second call is never working. You cannot reproduce the "bug", since the website is sandboxed, and i've tested on Google, and that works.

You need to know that the site i have tested on use a lot of angular JS based on GUI state. If someone still can explain me how can a uiwebview can be stuck from server side (webViewDidStartLoad never called), i'll be happy. So the bug is 100% server related.

Here the code:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIWebView* webview;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webview = _webview;

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{    
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    // With that ugly site it will be never called if _webview.hidden is set to true.
}

#pragma mark - lifeCycle

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self setUpWebView];

    // first time, it will work.
    [self performSelector: @selector(loadUrlString:) withObject: @"http://theUglySite.com" afterDelay: 1];

    // now, if the uiwebview is hidden, no response.
    [self performSelector: @selector(loadUrlString:) withObject: @"http://theUglySite.com" afterDelay: 3];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark - logic

- (void)setUpWebView{
    self.webview        = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,320,480}] autorelease];
    _webview.delegate   = self;

    // hidding the webView will break the delegate callBack. That will still work on normal
    // urlRequest.
    _webview.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview: _webview];
}

- (void)loadUrlString:(NSString*)urlString{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [_webview loadRequest: request];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Did you implement `UIWebviewDelegate` in your `.h` file ?

Comment: @AkshitZaveri if he hadn't implemented `UIWebviewDelegate` it would never call `webviewDidStartLoad` and `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` at all. So this must be implemented if it does make it to these methods in the end.

Comment: did you call  the Request on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, the code is running on the main thread. And my code works for every normal URL. But when it's that (bad) site, the things is that i need to call [webView reload] to make it happen, but the delegate calls are then called twice. If i don't do that nothing happen

Comment: I reiterate, please share your code. You haven't provided enough information for us to help you effectively.

Comment: @MrBonjour, share your code please.

Comment: If it is hidden it has no reason to call the delegate methods. That is the only reason I can think of it not calling them probably (Or correctly as it would seem).

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the webview in ios checks specifically for "iframe" tags in the html's dom and in case it finds, it creates events based on that tag as well. therefore, a simple however a patchy solution would be adding the following code in the part of the dom that is changing (for example, in the actual template of each section):

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

did the trick for me.. i'm also using angularjs version 1.3.16